# I have lost my Panasonic Eluga A3 mobile - Can i do Enable lock and Erase then can i access my phone back?

Tags: lost-phone

Hi i  have lost my Panasonic Eluga A3 mobile and i could see the last time when it was online was last morning 5:45 AM in chennai. The mobile has been switched off by the guy who has looted it. Now i know that the mobile has location ON but as the phone is OFF it is now showing anything on Android manager and i am not able to Ring it or Lock it. So the only option now i have is Erase Your device option. So if i do it now.. Then will i be able to again login to my Andriod device manager and track this mobile ? Is this the last option ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the phone is off you cant retrieve anything from it, the location that is showing to you is the latest location the phone could retrieve before it was switched off.

Trying to erase all the data will take place after the phone is turned on again and got any 4g - wifi signal on it.

> "Then will i be able to again login to my Andriod device manager and
>   track this mobile"

Answer - No, because of the above.

Hope it helps

Comment: "Then will i be able to again login to my Andriod device manager and track this mobile" I think you missed the answer to this question

Comment: Thanks Sir.. If i use the lock my Phone option with a message and contact number -- If the mobile is switched on with another sim put on it -- will it still make the phone locked with the message displayed on screen. ?

Comment: yes, lock my iphone is independient from your sim, it works with your apple account